# How to set y=rows and x=columns in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Before I get to my question, I should point out that I am new in R, and this question might be simplicity itself for an experienced user.
I want to use ggplot2 to take full advantage of all the functionalities therein. However, I have encountered a problem that I have not been able to solve.
If I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(100,35:65),rnorm(100,25:35),rnorm(100,15:20),rnorm(100,5:10),rnorm(100,0:5)))
header = c("A","B","C","D","E")
names(df) = make.names(header)
```

Plotting the data, where rows are Y and X is columns can readily be done in base R like e.g. this:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,0))
stripchart(df, vertical = TRUE, method = 'jitter')
boxplot(df)
```

[The picture shows the stripchart & boxplot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jEy9.jpg)

However, the same cannot readily be done in ggplot2, as `x` and `y` input are required. All examples I have found plots one column vs another column, or process the data into the column format. Yet, I want to set `y` as the rows in my `df` and the `x` as the columns. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You're trying to make boxplots?

Comment: I am aiming at making overlays of jitter+violin+box plots, but my data are generally in this shape, and I would like to be able to do this for any given type of applicable plots types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to reshape your data in order to get those graphs. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(reshape2) 
> df = as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(100,35:65),rnorm(100,25:35),rnorm(100,15:20),rnorm(100,5:10),rnorm(100,0:5)))
> header = c("A","B","C","D","E")
> names(df) = make.names(header)
> df = melt(df)
 No id variables; using all as measure variables
> head(df)
  variable    value
1        A 36.75505
2        A 35.68714
3        A 36.44952
4        A 38.77236
5        A 39.79136
6        A 39.39672

> ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value))
> ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_boxplot()
> ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_point(shape = 0, size = 20)
```

Here is the box plot: 
[image]

Here is the strip chart: 
[image]

You can change the settings in `aes()` options. See [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) for more info.

Comment: Read this post for some insight on when to use long vs. wide (your data) data:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590173/long-and-wide-data-when-to-use-what?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I can see how that would work for small data sets (like the random one I included), however, this solution moves all data into one column, and adds a new column with the previous column names. When datasets are larger, say 100+ variables, and hundreds of data entries, it seems that it would be a lot harder to work with an approach like this... None withstanding, your solution work, so thank you for that.

Comment: I've edited the post to include code to make the strip chart. If this solution works for you, please accept my answer.