# rowsums with multiple conditions

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate cumulative sum in rows with several variables.

This is my data as example. I have 5 patients ID, and 4 condition variables. If there is value between '1 to 3' in conditions, cumsum will be added 1.

```
ID<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
cond1<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
cond2<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
cond3<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
cond4<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
df<-data.frame(ID,cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4)
df

  ID cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4
1  a     2     7     6     6
2  b     7     2     3     6
3  c     4     3     1     4
4  d     7     3     3     6
5  e     6     7     7     3
```

I use `rowSums` code with following statement. However, as 2nd row, though `cond2` is 2 and `cond3` is 3, the `cumsum` was not '2',  '1'. 4nd row has same problem.

```
df$cumsum<-rowSums(df[,2:5]==c(1,2,3),na.rm=TRUE)
df
  ID cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 cumsum
1  a     2     7     6     6      0
2  b     7     2     3     6      1
3  c     4     3     1     4      1
4  d     7     3     3     6      1
5  e     6     7     7     3      0
```

How to make it cumulative? I would really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more than 1 element comparison, use `%in%`, but `%in%` works on a `vector`.   So, we loop through the columns with `lapply/sapply` and then do the `rowSums` on the logical matrix

```
df$RSum <- rowSums(sapply(df[,2:5], `%in%`, 1:3))
df$RSum
#[1] 1 2 2 2 1
```

---

If the values were numeric, then we could also make use of `>` or `<`

```
df$RSum <- rowSums(df[, 2:5] >=1 & df[, 2:5] <=3)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), cond1 = c(2L, 
7L, 4L, 7L, 6L), cond2 = c(7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L), cond3 = c(6L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 7L), cond4 = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you fix two problems with your data:

1. Your data is wide, instead of long formatted. Had your data been long formatted, your analysis would have been much simpler. This is specially true for plotting.
2. Your values for each condition are factors. That makes it more difficult to do comparissons, and might induce some difficult-to-spot errors. If you see @akrun answer carefully, you'll notice the values are integer (numeric).

That said, I propose a `data.table` solution:

```
# 1. load libraries and make df a data.table:
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# 2. make the wide table a long one
melt(df, id.vars = "ID")

# 3. with a long table, count the number of conditions that are in the 1:3 range for each ID. Notice I chained the first command with this second one:
melt(df, id.vars = "ID")[, sum(value %in% 1:3), by = ID]
```

Which produces the result:

```
   ID V1
1:  a  1
2:  b  2
3:  c  2
4:  d  2
5:  e  1
```

You'll only need to run commands under 1 and 3 (2 has been chained into 3). See `?data.table` for further details.

You can read more about wide vs long in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) and in [Mike Wise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590173/long-and-wide-data-when-to-use-what)

The data I used is the same as @akrun:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                          cond1 = c(2L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 6L), 
                          cond2 = c(7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L), 
                          cond3 = c(6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 7L), 
                          cond4 = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L)), 
               class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```