# Combine column values with partially matching names into one semicolon-separated field in R

Tags: r

I've looked through SO and have not found any advice that accurately explains what I am looking for.

I have a giant table. The first few columns have information about different expressed transcripts and the SNP which influences it. The remainder of the columns (of which there are around a thousand) are either information about an individual's tissue sample (with a column header such as `GTEX.11DXX.1426.SM.5GIDU`) or the individual's ID (`GTEX.11DXX`). The information under these columns contain either the number of transcripts expressed (e.g. `92`) at that particular sequence and a binary value representing whether the allele that influences the expression of that transcript is Neandertal inherited or not (`1 or 0`), respectively.

What I want to do is consolidate the data underneath the binary columns with the data underneath the transcript number columns like so:

```
GTEX.11DXX.1426.SM.5GIDU
0;25
1;74
1;104
1;92
0;12
...
etc.
```

I want to accomplish this by partially matching the column name `GTEX.11DXX` with `GTEX.11DXX.1426.SM.5GIDU`, and then getting rid of binary columns so it's just the long column names.

I've tried using `tidyverse`'s `map(v, ~select_(ovary, ~matches(.)))`, and it kind of works, but that matches even if a one character is off, like so:

```
[[49]]
       GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE GTEX.13X6H GTEX.13X6I GTEX.13X6J GTEX.13X6K
    1:                       49          0          0          0          1
    2:                       44          0          0          0          1
    3:                        3          0          0          0          1
    4:                       23          0          0          0          1
    5:                       78          0          0          0          1
   ---                                                                     
80285:                       84          1          0          0          0
80286:                        1          1          0          0          0
80287:                        0          1          0          0          0
80288:                      152          1          0          0          0
80289:                      120          1          0          0          0
```

Again, I want to to work like this:

```
       GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE
    1:                     0;49
    2:                     0;44
    3:                      0;3
    4:                     0;23
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems come because your data set is

- ...in wide format, meaning that data (individual names) is found in column headers. That makes it difficult to look up matching SNP <--> individual columns. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590173/long-and-wide-data-when-to-use-what) for information about what is wide *vs.* long data
- ... actually two data sets, merged together. One is about transcripts *vs.* number expressed (the long headers) and the other data set is transcripts *vs.* neandertal or not.

Therefore, put the tissue names and individual names into their own column instead of using them as column names! This is described in the following:

1. Create one data set (I call it `dataset1`) that has only information on allele counts. Do that by removing unnessecary columns. Only the following columns should remain:

   - a column with a unique transcript name
   - the columns of the pattern `GTEX.11DXX.1426.SM.5GIDU`
2. Create another data set (-> `dataset2`) similarly to above, but it includes only:

   - the column with the unique transcript name
   - the columns of the pattern `GTEX.11DXX`
3. Use [`tidyr::gather`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) or the newer [`tidyr::pivot*`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) (that I have no experience with yet) to get `dataset1` look like this

   ```
    transcript    tissue                    count
    A             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  49
    B             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  44
    C             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE   3
    ...
    A             GTEX.13X6I.1026.SM.5SIBE  10
    B             GTEX.13X6I.1026.SM.5SIBE  11
    ...
   ```

   and `dataset2` like this:

   ```
    transcript    individual   isNeandertal
    A             GTEX.13X6H   0
    B             GTEX.13X6H   0
    ...
    A             GTEX.13X6I   0           
    B             GTEX.13X6I   0
    ...
   ```
4. In data set 1, get the individual name from the tissue name, making the data set look like this:

   ```
   transcript    tissue                    individual  count
   A             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6H  49
   B             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6H  44
   C             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6H   3
   ...
   A             GTEX.13X6I.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6I  10
   B             GTEX.13X6I.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6I  11
   ...
   ```
5. Now you can use `dplyr::full_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("transcript", "individual"))` to merge the allele counts and the neandertal status.

   This works only if each combination of (transcript, individual) occurs **only once per data set**! If these columns have the same combination in multiple rows, `full_join` does  not know which rows from `dataset1` and `dataset2` belong together and will output all combinations of them!

   Check this by
   `stopifnot(!anyDuplicated(dataset1[, c("transcript", "individual")]))` and
   `stopifnot(!anyDuplicated(dataset2[, c("transcript", "individual")]))`(with your 
   variable names, of course)

The result of this step should look like this:

```
    transcript    tissue                    individual  count  isNeandertal
    A             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6H  49     0
    B             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6H  44     0
    C             GTEX.13X6H.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6H   3     0
    ...
    A             GTEX.13X6I.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6I  10     0
    B             GTEX.13X6I.1026.SM.5SIBE  GTEX.13X6I  11     0
    ...
```

6. Now you can paste together the columns `count` and `isNeandertal`